# How to set Conditional Row Number by specific values from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns table and based on value (if that exists) I want to set row_number.
I have some solution but it looks long and I think could be easier and less code (best option) to handle it. Below sample with expected results:

**If query returns Client with NULL:**

```
----------------------
Process | Client|

  A     | NULL  |
  A     | B     |
  A     | B     |
  A     | B     |
  A     | C     |
  A     | C     |
  A     | C     |
```

**OutPut should be:**

```
    ----------------------
Process | Client| RowNumber

  A     | NULL  | 1
  A     | B     | 2
  A     | B     | 3
  A     | B     | 4
  A     | C     | 2
  A     | C     | 3
  A     | C     | 4
```

**If query returns without NULL:**

```
----------------------
Process | Client|

  A     | B     |
  A     | B     |
  A     | B     |
  A     | C     |
  A     | C     |
  A     | C     |
```

**OutPut should be:**

```
    ----------------------
Process | Client| RowNumber

  A     | B     | 1
  A     | B     | 2
  A     | B     | 3
  A     | C     | 1
  A     | C     | 2
  A     | C     | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `NULL` should always be treated as `'B'`, but you need to handle that:

```
select t.* ,
       row_number() over (partition by process, coalesce(client, 'B') order by (select null))
from t
where client is not null;
```

Oh, I see, you are not setting the `NULL` to `'B'` but adding the number of `NULL`s to the other values.  That is also quite simple:

```
select t.* ,
       (row_number() over (partition by process, client order by (select null)) +
        (case when client is null then 0
               else sum(case when client is null then 1 else 0 end) over ()
         end)
       )
from t
where client is not null;
```

Comment: @LBman . . . It is more general than the answer you have (currently) accepted, because it works for any number of `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91fb4bd752add40ffb0f7d5210626c9d)

```
DROP TABLE if exists mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable(Process char(1), Client char(1));

INSERT INTO mytable values
  ('A',null),
  ('A','B'),
  ('A','B'),
  ('A','B'),
  ('A','C'),
  ('A','C'),
  ('A','C');


-- with a NULL value
select 
   Process, 
   Client, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by process,Client order by (select null))+CASE WHEN Client is null THEN 0 else 1 end R 
from mytable;

-- without a NULL value
select 
   Process, 
   Client, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by process,Client order by (select null)) R 
from mytable
where not client is null;
```

Comment: Thanks @Luuk, but as I said query can return in some cases with "null" and sometimes without "null" client. I want to handle it in one select query so it should cover both scenario. I think we might add "when exists" to check and cover both scenario

Answer (score 1):

…

```
declare @t table(process varchar(10), client varchar(10));

insert into @t(process, client)
values
('A', null),
('A', 'B'),('A', 'B'),('A', 'B'),
('A', 'C'),('A', 'C'),
('A', ''), ('A', ''), ('A', ' '), ('A', ' '), 
('A', 'ZXY'), ('A', 'ZXY'),
('X', 'B'),('X', 'B'),('X', 'B'),
('X', 'C'),('X', 'C');

select *, 
row_number() over(partition by process,client order by client)
--if there is a null client per process then add 1 to every non null client
+ case when client is not null and min(case when client is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by process) = 0 then 1 else 0 end
--+ case when client is not null and min(isnull(ASCII(client+'.'), 0)) over(partition by process) = 0 then 1 else 0 end
as rownumber
from 
(
select * 
from @t
--where client is not null
) as t;
```